# CollectionView fails to render with empty collection

Tags: events, marionette, collectionview

Why won't my Marionette CollectionView work with an empty collection?

I'm trying to render a CollectionView within a CompositeView (it's a list of tasks within each item of a list of projects). Everything works fine until I pass an empty collection into the CollectionView. The collection *is* allowed to be empty; a project can easily have no tasks assigned to it.

The error shown by Chrome is

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

The collection of projects passed in *is* a valid `Backbone.Collection`, **as are the task lists returned by the filter methods of `TasksCollection`**, which is why I can't work out why the error above is shown.

Marionette's CollectionView can accept an empty collection (it has an `emptyView` property), so why is it giving an error when one is passed in? I assume it's trying to bind events to the collection which should "just work" - it's only the models that are absent.

My tasks collection looks like this:

```
var TasksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TaskModel,
    byProject: function(projectId) {
        var matches = this.filter(function(task) {
            return task.get('projectId') == projectId;
        }, this);

        return new TasksCollection (matches);
    },
    complete: function(state) {
        return new TasksCollection (this.where({ complete: state }));
    }
});
```

My views look like this:

```
// Single task item
var TasksListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'tasks nav nav-stacked nav-pills',
    itemView: Minuteboy.views.TaskItem,
    emptyView: Templates['partials/tasks-empty']
});

// Project item (should probably be a Layout or CompositeView)
var DashboardProject = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'article',
    template: Templates['partials/dashboard-project'],
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('render', function() {
            var tasks = AllProjectTasks.byProject(this.model.get('id')).complete(false);

            this.$el.find('.tasks-wrapper').html(new TasksListView({ 
                collection: tasks
            }).render().el);
        });
    }
});

// Containing view with page title and container for projects list
var DashboardPage = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Templates['pages/dashboard'],
    itemView: DashboardProject,
    itemViewContainer: '#content'
});
```

Finally, I instantiate the page view like this:

```
var page = new DashboardPage({
    collection: // A valid Backbone.Collection
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an error on my part. Instead of using some sort of view object for the `emptyView` property of my CollectionView, I was just using a template (Handlebars in this case). My working CollectionView looks like this:

```
var EmptyList = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: Templates['partials/tasks-empty']
});

Minuteboy.views.TaskList = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'tasks nav nav-stacked nav-pills',
    itemView: Minuteboy.views.TaskItem,
    emptyView: EmptyList
});
```

Note the `itemView` line:

```
itemView: Minuteboy.views.TaskItem
```

This used to be

```
itemView: Templates['partials/tasks-empty']
```

Which is **bad**.